# Json returns a duplicate value using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch a data for each chkey with a related value as a group in codeigniter. When there are a 2 or more chkey then code is work properly.
 But when there is a only 1 chkey then it shows value of that chkey but it is  shows extra chkey:null,value:null in json.
 Related json for  chkey is 1 is as follows'

```
[{"unit_id":"8","CHGRAPHUpdatetime":{"time":"2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00"},"channelGraph":[{"chkey":"ch1","list":"2,-30,12,20"},{"chkey":"null","list":"null"}]}]
```

Expected is,

```
[{"unit_id":"8","CHGRAPHUpdatetime":{"time":"2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00,2018-03-15 00:00:00"},"channelGraph":[{"chkey":"ch1","list":"2,-30,12,20"}]}]
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

model code-

```
 public function chGraph($unitid){
           $this->db->select("unit_id");
           $this->db->from("device_unit");
           $this->db->where('unit_id', $unitid);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           $unit = $query->result_array();
           $j = 0;
     foreach($unit as $row) {
         $unit[$j]['CHGRAPHUpdatetime'] = $this->UnitCHGRAPHUpdatetime($row['unit_id']);
           $unit[$j++]['channelGraph'] = $this->UnitCHGRAPHDetails1($row['unit_id']);


      }
      return $unit;
      }
        public function UnitCHGRAPHDetails1($unit_id)
    { 
        $this->db->select('distinct(chkey)','chvalue');
        $this->db->from('channel_info'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $channelgraphData = $query->result_array();
        $m = 0;

      foreach($channelgraphData as $row) {
           $chvalueQuery = 'SELECT chkey, GROUP_CONCAT(chvalue)as list FROM channel_info where chkey= "'. $row['chkey'] .'"  and unit_id='. $unit_id .'';
           $response = $this->db->query($chvalueQuery)->row(); 
           $channelgraphData[$m++] = $response;
        }
        return $channelgraphData;
    }
```

controller code-

```
  public function chGraph()
  {
     $unitid =  $this->uri->segment('3');
     $GraphDetails = $this->device_model->chGraph($unitid);
    echo json_encode($GraphDetails);
  }
```

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to see whether it's based on the database stuff or combining the database results in PHP?

Comment: There is no code above that produces JSON output (e.g. `json_encode`). You error might come from anywhere. Please try to find a reproducable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `GROUP BY` at the end of the statement to eliminate the `null` results :

```
    $chvalueQuery = 'SELECT chkey, GROUP_CONCAT(chvalue)as list FROM channel_info where chkey= "'. $row['chkey'] .'"  and unit_id='. $unit_id .' GROUP BY chkey';
```